# Confusing C++ situation

Tags: c++, recursion

This is a really stupid question, but I need a little reassurance/assistance. I have the current "recursive" situation:

```
void add( int value )
{
  // do something ... //

  if ( condition ) {
    add(myVal);
    acc = 0;
  }
}
```

My question is whether the variable `acc` will eventually be set to zero. It should, right? Even if the condition doesn't hold true the second time around (upon the recursion). It'll just finish performing the function and proceed with setting `acc` to 0 .. I think / hope?

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm not posting complete code because I don't think it's necessary. It's a bit lengthy. It's worth mentioning that the `condition` is not always true. Therefore, this recursion is not infinite.

EDIT 2: The max recursions is 2. That is, if the condition holds true the first time, it will outcome false the second time (upon recursion), avoiding an infinite loop. To clarify my question: Consider the situation where the condition first outcomes true, so the recursion takes place. After the function finishes (the outcome will be false during the recursion) and exits, it'll exit to the original function, and that will exit as well. Upon exiting, will it continue where it left off, that is, setting acc=0 and then returning? One of the answers below provided a good explanation for this.

Comment: I promise this is not homework

Comment: I don't see any code that influences `condition` at all.

Comment: Please post real code. Preferably a **complete, minimal, working** example.

Comment: How is condition affected? And why would you expect to be different from the first time you call it.

Comment: Your code is really too incomplete to say much about it. You haven't told/showed us what (if anything) sets `condition` (or under what circumstances), what value `myVal` has, etc. Without knowing these things, you question just can't be answered.

Comment: It will be too difficult to post *complete* code since this is a function that's part of a large program. It would be meaningless even in it's *complete* form. The condition that is being tested almost never holds true, therefore the recursion almost never happens. When it does happen, it tests for the condition again, and the condition will be false, so it'll be able to get out of the recursion loop. My question is, when it tests for the condition and gets a false statement, it will exit the function, but will it set acc to zero?

Comment: Somebody has a lot of spare reputation to waste today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the recursive call to `add` returns, yes, the value of `acc` inside of the function that made the recursive call in the first place will indeed be set to zero.  You can think of the code as working like this:

```
if ( condition ) {
  make a call to add(myVal);
  wait for that call to return;
  acc = 0;
}
```

An important detail, though, is that, assuming that `acc` is a local variable in the function, it will only be set to zero in the *calling* function, not the recursive call you made.  For example, if your code looks like this:

```
void add( int value )
{
  int acc = 1;
  cout << acc << endl;

  if ( condition ) {
    add(myVal);
    acc = 0;
  }
}
```

Then if you do make the recursive call you indicated, the output of the `cout` statement in the recursive call will still be `1`, because the value of `acc` in this particular recursive call is independent of the value of `acc` in other recursive calls.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I wanted to hear. +1

Comment: if condition is false on the first check, neither his code nor your code will set acc to 0.

Comment: @Mooing Duck- Why is that?  Perhaps the condition involves randomness, user input, the parameter, or some other value that varies from call to call.  In fact, the OP guarantees this.  This means that if it's false the first time around, it doesn't necessarily mean that it will always be false.  Most recursive functions work this way.

Comment: @templatetypedef: You seem to have misunderstood me.  My comment only was about the first call.  Your answer is correct on the assumption that acc need only to be set to zero if the condition is true the first call.

Comment: @Mooing Duck- Ah, I see.  I was interpreting the question to mean "assuming that I actually make this recursive call, will `acc` be set to zero?" rather than "even if this condition is false, will `acc` be set to zero?"

Comment: I admit, the question is ambiguous.  On reading his edits, I _think_ your guess is correct that acc only need be set to 0 in the case of recursion, but it's unclear.

Comment: @templatetypedef: That is exactly what I meant in the question.
Mooing Duck: I apologize for not making the question clear enough. Sort of been stuck in this code for a while and was just making sure this wasn't my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If condition is false from the beginning, acc will not be set to zero.  Otherwise, yes it will.

So, the only thing that will affect whether acc get's set to zero is the value of condition the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, functions return right after the point they got called, so your `acc` will get set to 0.

Note that if it's global, it will be set to 0 multiple times over and over as you're returning from recursion, while if it's local, and that's the end of your function, it might not do anything useful (read, it will get optimized out by your compiler).

Comment: acc will never be 0 if the first condition check is false.

Comment: +1 to counter silly downvote. The question might be worded confusingly, but this actually answers it.

Answer (score -2):

As others have said, if acc is local, this does nothing, and if acc is not local, this is redundant.  Also, there is no guarantee that acc will be set to zero if condition is false on the first call.  You probably want this:

```
void add( int value )
{
  // do something ... //    
  if ( condition ) {
    add(myVal); //if condition is true, recurse.
  } else {
    acc = 0; //else, set acc to zero once and escape all the recursion
  }
}
```

> Upon exiting, will it continue where it left off, that is, setting acc=0 and then returning?

Yes.